# Azure functions, BlobTrigger, Connection, App settings

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-trigger

So I am trying to get appsetting for `BlobTriggerAttribute.Connection` property, and it has hierarchical style name (as I need to map it later to `IConfiguration`), and I am struggling with naming conventions. So as far as I know the common approach is to use `__`(double underscore) to separate hierarchical sections, but there is one more approach which is `:` and it has its own disadvantages (like environment variables names can't contain this symbol). So that's how my blob trigger parameter attribute looks like

[image: Blob trigger attribute]

That's how I build `ConnectionName` constant

[image: Connection name]

And that's the delimiter constant

[image: Delimiter]

Here is my `settings.local.json`

[image: settings.local.json]

When I am running it locally, I am getting this error

[image: Error message]

But when I am changing the delimiter to `:` it works... But when I am rebuilding my app it gives a warning like this one

[image: Warning]

Is that some well known issue? And what kind of approach should I use here?

(Running locally on Windows machine, `<AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after digging into Azure Functions Webhost sources I found a place where they are [resolving](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/3f4ec78be9f43bb041937425ced00b341883aa42/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/Extensions/IConfigurationExtensions.cs#L15) actual connection. Seems like they are going through `IConfiguration` and trying to get value by at first prefixed (using [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/3f4ec78be9f43bb041937425ced00b341883aa42/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/Constants.cs#L8) constant) and then non prefixed key. So in this case it seems that `IConfiguration` separator convention should be used (which is `:`).
The only bad thing that [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationpath.keydelimiter?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) separator is `static readonly`, so in the end you can't use that value in attribute, so it have to be hardcoded...